# Debian checking resulting in no

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

I have a home server running Debian Lenny. I am trying to install iStat Server on it, but it just doesn't want to work. 
I got it working on an other server, also running lenny... it worked straigt "out of the box".

When I run the configure script, this is what I get:

```
~/istatd-0.5.7# ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/root/istatd-0.5.7':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your c++ compiler. Try to install gcc and g++ (Not sure exactly how the packages are named in debian, it might be gcc-c++).

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing other development packages as well, but at a bare minimum you need to install the `build-essential` package and its dependencies.

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

Depending on what you're trying to build, you may need other development libraries, headers, and so forth. For example, [your project's](https://github.com/tiwilliam/istatd) readme.txt clearly lists `libxml2-dev` as a dependency, so you'll need to include that as well.